# wget download using list of urls

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download several files with `wget`. The relevant URLs are stored in the file `url.txt`. When using the command `wget --content-disposition -i url.txt` it doesn't find the .txt file.

Where do I have to store the url.txt file?

Comment: Does it give you any indications of a error msg?

Comment: @Chris: In that case please check if that path exists or not.And also check for the read permission of that file.By looking at your command that is `wget --content-disposition -i url.txt` you should execute this command in the directory where your url.txt is present.Because you are not giving an absolute path to `wget`.

Comment: if you use that syntax the `url.txt` needs to be in the same directory in which you run `wget`

Comment: @ Thushi: how would the command look like if I would give an absolute path?

Comment: @Chris : Hmmm...It's a complete path like `wget --content-disposition -i /home/Chris/Samples/url.txt`

Comment: @ Thushi: Thank's a lot, now it is working. just, how can I determine where to store the files?

Comment: @Chris: It's not clear. What files are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

You should give your URLs with `http://`

Your `url.txt` should have

```
  http://www.google.com
  http://www.yahoo.com
```

If you don't have the protocol included you'll get messages stating the following:

```
$ wget --content-disposition  -i url.txt 
url.txt: Invalid URL www.google.com: Scheme missing
url.txt: Invalid URL www.yahoo.com: Scheme missing
```

Comment: @ Thushi: to put it in other words, what is the most suitable command to access the url.txt file to download the data?

Comment: @Chris: It is a different question.May be you should ask another question for this.You can use `wget` `curl` and some other utilities.

Comment: If this is the problem, it would be trivial to fix the file with sed, ed, vim, or any other editor with regular expressions. Something like: `sed -i '/^http:\/\//!s/^/http:\/\//' url.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that file should be in .html format containing URL please refer 
wget man page .
-i file
--input-file=file
Read URLs from file, in which case no URLs need to be on the command line. If there are URLs both on the command line and in an input file, those on the command lines will be the first ones to be retrieved. The file need not be an HTML document (but no harm if it is)---it is enough if the URLs are just listed sequentially.
However, if you specify --force-html, the document will be regarded as html. In that case you may have problems with relative links, which you can solve either by adding "" to the documents or by specifying --base=url on the command line.

Thanks